# How to ensure that re-sizing doesn't break my GUI

Tags: algorithm, opengl, user-interface

I've done a few little games here and there, same for GUI programs but I can't seem to make things re-sizable. Most GUIs handle re-sizing fairly well, but how is this achieved?

Lets say we have a 600x800 window, which has a 100x100 box in the very center, and another identical box 200x above it. If I stretched the window to 1280x720, what algorithm would ensure nothing slips out of place while moving and re-sizing the buttons to the new resolution?

I'd like this to apply to "pixel by pixel" displays, such as drawing a centered quad on the screen is where you tell at which pixel each vertex is, not something scalable such as OpenGL's default matrix.

Comment: Are you using Xwindow, glWindow, or drawing your own window ? Also can you show us your code ..

Comment: I'm talking about any GUI framework in general. But more specifically custom frameworks, such as drawing things in OpenGL.

Comment: There's no general solution, each framework has its own dynamics

Comment: if a window would crash if there are number of components drawn over its borders, then logically if the new window is bigger then re-size the window first, if the new window is smaller then re-size the components first.

Comment: This is how I do it: Look at everything as if they are points relative to the windowborders, so instead of a box at the center, you have a box at 0.5x and 0.5y, then similarly explain its size based on the size of your screen (100/1280x). Then when you draw, you take these points and multiply by whatever screen size you want, and everything will end up in the correct position at any screen size. If you need some static components (you might not want scaling text etc) you will need to adapt it cleverly to your needs. Pointer: choose a min and max size for all windows. It's not very flexible tho

Comment: I am currently working on a GUI library, and this problems is far not easy. All widgets may have minimum size, maximum size and in some case has a size proportional to another widgets, etc: For example a input box has probably a constant height but a variable width.
You should consider all options and resolve step by step, but that may take a very long work-time.